# Why is Visual Studio making beep while running in debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am running a project in the debug configuration in VS2012 and the IDE intermittently beeps. I ran said project numerous times before and never experienced such a behavior. Is VS trying to draw my attention to something? How can I disable the beeps?

Comment: I really hate random audio alerts, especially when they happen repeatedly, and it's not clear what process fired them. *What are you trying to tell me?!?*

Comment: I made sure it's Visual Studio issuing the beeps by pausing the run. There were no beeps during the pause. The question remains: Why is Visual Studio suddenly doing that?

Comment: Just to clarify, this doesn't happen in release, right? Have you tried setting breakpoints/stepping through it?

Comment: You could try debugging Visual Studio (with either another debugger another instance of VS =p) and setting a breakpoint on the [`{,,user32.dll}_MessageBeep@4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  That would give a call stack which might indicate the source of the beeps (you may also need symbols from the [Microsoft Symbol Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503)).

Comment: I never run said project using the release configuration as I arbitrarily put break points to see what's going on under the hood (breaking works pretty well).

Comment: In Control Panel->Sound->Sounds tab there are some entries for VS2012. Otherwise, does the "beep" correspond to any of the other types of sound, e.g. Asterisk or Exclamation?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I checked the entries in the control panel. None of them has a sound assigned. Strange thing is, the beep comes through my speakers but does not sound like a tone that is played back. It rather sounds like the system beep. The beep cannot correspond to any other event since I disabled all those sounds.

Comment: Might you be outputting a Chr(7) character to something which interprets it as the BEL character and thus beeps?

Comment: I just tried to include that character in a string and it made the same beep. I know that all output I make does not include the BEL character, but since the project fetches and transfers large sets of data and giving me a summarization in the Console it might be there are some hidden BELs in the data processed. I will dig into the database and check the last records for occurrences of that sound.

Comment: Ok, I dug some tuples and none of them contained said character. But as it turns out, writing the character '•' (\x8226) to the Console causes a beep as well (the dot itself cannot be printed). One record contained that dot. Since it has been processed by different stages (whose order and quantity vary) those beeps seemed intermittently to me. So last thing to find out is why the Console beeps this character (8226 is 33318 decimal and does not has the same bits set as 7 [ just as a starting point :) ]).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with beeping while debugging code in Visual Studio and it turned out that the root cause was a KVM switch, like this one: http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/4-port-usb-kvm-switch/ actually the source of beeping sound was the switch while pressing F10 or F11 buttons on keyboard connected to the switch. After plugging external devices like mouse and keyboard directly to the PC, the problem disappeared.